# Limit the Kinect Detection Distance

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, kinect

I'm building a kinect driven .net app, is it possible to limit the kinect's detection distance?

Its like i have an interactive shopping window that is controlled by a kinect, i want only the person who steps on the X mark on the ground to be detected or lets say the person who is 3 meters far from the sensor to be detected.
If anybody is closer than the 3 meters or farther than that it wouldn't detect him.

I use VB.Net for coding although most of the codes are translated from C#, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: No you can't limit the detection distance. But since the Kinect detects distance, you can just ignore all data < 3 m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your SkeletonFrameReady callback, you likely have a `foreach` loop (or similar) to step through your active skeletons.  You should also be looking to see if they are actively tracked.

```
foreach (Skeleton skeleton in _skeletons) {

    // some extra setup stuff here...

    if (skeleton.TrackingState != SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
      return;

    // the Kinect is actively tracking the skeleton at this point

    ...
}
```

What you want to do at this point is check the `Z` position of the person.  Pick a joint you want to use as reference -- I'd suggest the head, hip or spine.  If the `Z` position is where you want it to be, continue to act on the skeleton.

```
foreach (Skeleton skeleton in _skeletons) {
    ....

    if (skeleton.TrackingState != SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
      return;

    if (skeleton.Joints[JointType.Spine].Position.Z < _minValue || skeleton.Joints[JointType.Spine].Position.Z > _maxValue)
      return;

    // if you reach this point, the person is standing a certain distance from the Kinect.  Not too close, not too far away.

}
```

You will want to check a range for the `Z` position.  It can be a small range, but you want to give the user enough space to move a little without the Kinect ignoring them.

**UPDATE:** You may also be able to use the `Position` property from the `Skeleton`.  It has a single x/y/z reference to a calculated point for the entire skeleton in the Kinect's FOV.

Comment: Thanks alot buddy, will give it a shot and update you with the status

Comment: I noticed my code sample for checking if the user is within a certain distance was incorrect, based on the result.  I've updated the code to be correct.

Comment: I agree with @Evil Closet Monkey, The provided code will work

Comment: Accepting helpful answers, past and present, is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go through all detected skeletons and set the skeleton as the main skeleton whose center joint's Z-position is at the X-mark-distance. Consider a tolerance of 60cm.